# java- method cannot be found from non static

Tags: java, static

I have 2 classes, dog and printing, the dog class is meant to send over a char[][] to printing so it can print to a printer. However, the dog class can't find the printing method in printing class.

```
//Printing class-
public class Printing implements Printable, ActionListener {
    String str = "";

    public String printString(char [][] grid ){  
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<9;j++){    
                str += String.valueOf(grid[i][j]);
            }
            str += "\n";
        } 
        return str;
    }
}
```

I then require this str in another method as well.
When I type `Printing.printString(grid);` it cannot be referenced from static context. When I change it to `public static String(char [][] grid )` its method then can't find the str string variable.

Comment: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/methods/50static-methods.html

Comment: *Please* learn about scopes, visibility and static/non-static behaviour in Java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `Printing.printString(grid);` like this unless you make it a static.

Also if you made `printString()` method as a static you need to declare `str` as a static because you cant refer a non-static variables within a static methods.

So you code should look like this:

```
public class Printing  implements Printable, ActionListener {
static String str = "";

    public String printString(char [][] grid ){  
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<9;j++){    
                str += String.valueOf(grid[i][j]);
            }
            str += "\n";
        } 
        return str;
    }
}
```

Read more about static [variables and methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `str` member must also be static. Just make sure that you reset it with each call to `printString`.

```
  class Printing
  {
    private static String str = "";

    public static printString( char[][] grid )
    {
      str = "";

      for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
      {
        for (int j=0;j<9;j++)
        {
          str += String.valueOf(grid[i][j]);
        }

        str += "\n";
      }

      return str;
    }
  }
```

Also, this isn't really part of the question, but I recommend the use of the `StringBuffer` class in situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

this will help

```
public String printString(char [][] grid ){  
     String str = "";

        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<9;j++){    
                str += String.valueOf(grid[i][j]);
            }
            str += "\n";
        } 
        return str;
}
```

Comment: i require the str string in another method to be edited aswell, thats why i declared it outside the method

Comment: Then you should refactor the code. It's not of the best quality, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
static String str = "";

 public static String printString(char [][] grid ){  
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<9;j++){    
                str += String.valueOf(grid[i][j]);
            }
            str += "\n";
        } 
        return str;
}
```

Now you can call the method using `Printing.printString(grid);`

The non-static instance variable can't be refer in static class and vice versa

Comment: dangerous, as you keep str as a static field. My solution is slightly better

Comment: hmmm... considering the level of code, you better not introduce any modifiable static fields, as this will introduce bugs to it.

Comment: 'you better not introduce any modifiable static fields' what it mean @Funtik